# Python - How use properties without creating an object

Tags: python

How do I write a class to make this code work.

```
class number:

    def double(self):
        return n*2

print(number(44).double)
>> 88
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could decorate the *number.double* method with [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class number:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    @property
    def double(self):
        return self.number * 2


print(number(42).double) # 84
```

If you know the type of your argument, it'd be better to inherit `number` from it. For example

```
class number(int):
    @property
    def double(self):
        return type(self)(self * 2)

print(number(42).double) # 84
print(number(42).double.double) # 168
```

Comment: Don't know why you're subclassing int when they're seem to be trying to write a generic numeric class.

Comment: @L3viathan `number('Too generic huh?').double`

Comment: behaviour seems fine by me! If you don't want that, check for `int`, `float`, `long`, and `complex`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
class Number(object):

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def double(self):
        return 2*self.n

print(Number(44).double())
```

A couple of notes:

1. Since `double()` is a method of the class `Number` (and not an attribute), you need to use parentheses to call it.
2. In Python it's considered standard practice to give classes uppercase names.
3. If you want to define an instance variable (in this case `n`, or `44`, you must `def` the `__init__()` function which gives the interpreter instructions for how to create, or initialize an instance of your class.

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: I am making an exercise on codewars and I need to use the following syntaxe. I don't think I can use a method. Here is the test case. test.assert_equals(PrimeFactorizer(24).factor, {2: 3, 3: 1})

Comment: Do you have the code or documentation for ```test.assert_equals()```. I'm almost positive that ```test.assert_equals()``` takes the actual function as an argument (rather than the value returned by calling the function), so that it can call the function itself. If this is so, then ```PrimeFactorizer.factor()``` is really a method even though you don't use parentheses when using it that particular way.